# OpenNMT-py summarization runtime

Tags: python, nlp, summarization

I ran the transformer script of OpenNMT-py summarization on an AWS gpu for almost 22 hrs (only with 30% of the cnndm data). Anyone has an idea how long it can take?? Thanks! 
   https://opennmt.net/OpenNMT-py/Summarization.html

```
[2020-02-06 20:15:24,151 INFO] encoder: 38212608
[2020-02-06 20:15:24,151 INFO] decoder: 42469717
[2020-02-06 20:15:24,151 INFO] * number of parameters: 80682325
[2020-02-06 20:15:24,154 INFO] Starting training on GPU: [0]
[2020-02-06 20:15:24,154 INFO] Start training loop and validate every 10000 steps...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Mon Feb 10 16:10:25 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.01    Driver Version: 418.87.01    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla M60           On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   47C    P0    48W / 150W |   3691MiB /  7618MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      6078      C   -                                              2MiB |
|    0     88254      C   /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/python         3045MiB |
|    0     88255      C   /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/python          630MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```